# How do I replace a text with a specific index on a table in Java?

Tags: java

I currently have this school project for the management of a store and I really don't know how to make this replacement. The variable names are currently in my native language. This is for the editing part:

```
public static void Modify() { 
    String mod=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the id code of the seller you want to modify: "); 
    int mod1 = new Integer(mod).intValue(); 
    while (i == mod1){ 
        Store.setName(getName()); 
        Store.setSurname(surname); 
        Store.setId(getID()); 
        Store x=new Store(getName(), surname, getID()); 
        Info[i]=x; 
        System.out.println("Registered seller "+ getName() +" "+ surname);
    }
}
```

Also I did this for searching thru it and won't work:

```
public static void Search(){
    String code1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the code of the seller you are searching for: ");
    int code = new Integer(code1).intValue();
    String answer = Store.getName();
    for (int i=0; i<numri;i++){
        if (Store.getID()==code)
        {
            answer=Store.getName();
            System.out.println("The seller you are looking for is: " + answer);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("The seller you are looking for cannot be found");
        break;
    }
}
```

It only prints the last one.

And here is the whole code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Store{
    private static String name;
    public static String surname;
    private static int ID;

  static String nr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the number of sellers you want to register: ");
static int number=new Integer(nr).intValue();

 static Store[] Info = new Store[number];
private static int i;
//Input of info
public Store(String name, String surname, int id) {

    }
public static void setName(String namee){
    String e = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the sellers name: ");
    setname(e);
}
public static void setSurname(String surnamee){
    String m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the sellers surname: ");
    surname=m;
}
public static void setId(int ID){
    String ID1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the id code of the seller: ");
    int Id=new Integer(ID1).intValue();
    ID=Id;
}

public static void FillTable() //Registering sellers
{for (int i =0; i<number; i++){
    Store.setName(getName());
    Store.setSurname(surname);
    Store.setId(getID());
    Store x=new Store(getName(), surname, getID());
    Info[i]=x;
    System.out.println("Registered seller "+ getname() +" "+ surname);}}

//Search
public static void Search(){
    String code1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the code of the seller you want to find: ");
    int code = new Integer(code1).intValue();
    String answer = Store.getName();
    for (int i=0; i<number;i++){
        if (Store.getID()==code)
        {answer=Store.getname();
        System.out.println("The seller you are searching for is: " + answer);
        break;
        }
        else System.out.println("The seller cannot be found.");
        break;
        }


}

// Modifying the sellers
public static void Modify(){
String mod=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the code of the seller you want to modify: ");
 int mod1 = new Integer(mod).intValue();
 while (i == mod1){
     Store.setName(getname());
        Store.setSurname(surname);
        Store.setId(getID());
        Store x=new Store(getName(), surname, getID());
        Info[i]=x;
        System.out.println("Edited seller "+ getName() +" "+ surname);}}




private static void remove(int f) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Store.FillTable();
    Store.Search();
    Store.Modify();
    }
public static int getID() {
    return ID;
}
public static void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}
public static String getName() {
    return name;
}
public static void setName(String name) {
    Store.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please translate the method and variable names to English?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson edited :)

Comment: Well your code is really strange. For example `Store.setName(getName())`. Is "Store" a class and "setName(..)" a static method or is this an object (then you should name in "store" and not "Store") ? If this is an object, where do you get it from ? And were does the i variable come from ?

Comment: Store is a class and setName is a static method, the i is a variable that will look up into the array called Info, it takes the values from 0 to the user input value @lvr123

Comment: In `Modify`, `i` seems to be a fix value. Fixed a wich value ? Your code doesn't say it. In `Search`, you loop on `i` , but how is this variable relates with what you get from `Store.getNanme()` ? How does a change in i cause a change in `Store.getName()` ?
You should post your `Store`  and `Info` classes along. 
Are your sure static methods are the right solution ?

Comment: Not sure about all of that, that's what we were taught in school. And is crap so far, that's why I posted here.. looking for the best solution for it.. in Modify i had another one on the if part but changed it due to some things i saw online, anyways as I said I'm not sure about anything.. @lvr123

Comment: add your Store and Info code and we'll see what we can get out of it.

Comment: @lvr123 check the last edit

Comment: =8-O Honestly, I don't understand what your code does !!! You have completely messed up with the concepts of Objects, Classes, .... You should get back to the very basic of Java programming : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html
Now a few words about what doesn't work in your code, as far as I understand : you initiate x *objects* of _class_ `Store` that you put in an Store array (`Info`). But this _class_ has only static properties. (./..)

Comment: (../.) That means that they are set at _class_ level and not _object_ level.  These values are therefor shared among all *objects* of this _class_. This means that every time you instantiate a new `Store` *object* with new `name`, `surname`and `id`, it overrides the _class_ -level values and therefor propagates to all the `Store` *objects*. All your `Store` *objects* always have the same values. That's the reason why it looks like your code always returns the last Store.

Comment: @lvr123 can you help me with the changes I need for that? I really dont know what to do.. Honestly.

Comment: @8diti Well I won't do that for you. I can write you a skeleton. First thing you have to tell me is what are the default name, surname and ids of a Store object.

Answer (score 0):

Java internationalization of strings can be done through the [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class. A quick example of what it looks like in use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationMessages", Locale.FRANCE);
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("CountryName"));
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("CurrencyCode"));
}
```

Here's a short [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1370/java-internationalization-i18n-example-tutorial) on how to get started with it, you can Google around for more examples. It is easy to use, but be careful - it is also easy to leave out a string for one locale on accident.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll need this.

Comment: To be honest, I thought the question was about internationalization of strings. Now that it has been edited a few times, I can't tell.